# kvm disabled by bios after installing nVidia driver

Tags: drivers, graphics, bios

Whenever I try to switch from the nouveau driver to any nVidia driver (304, 310 or nvidia-current) and reboot my machine after selecting a driver Ubuntu boots with the following error:

```
[2.4556] kvm: disabled by bios
[2.4556] kvm: disabled by bios
[2.4556] kvm: disabled by bios
```

The numbers in front of the text are always something in the form of `2.xxx`.

Is there anyone else experiencing problems? My graphics card is the nVidia GTX550 Ti

Comment: Are you sure the erros don't appear with the Nouveau driver?

Comment: this number is count of process . and i know only it :)

Comment: @stonedsquirrel I'm positive. If I use the nouveau driver everything works like a charm, except for games that is.

Answer (score 3):

I got rid of these errors by enabling CPU virtualizaton in the BIOS.